# Import Data from csv file with Matlab

Tags: matlab, import

I got a problem to import data from scientific experiments with matlab. the import tool does not work with the amount of data. so i need a script. i am new to matlab, so i looked up the documentary. i found `csvread` and `dlmread`.

My files look like this:
MS spectrum:

```
#"-ESI Scan (11.86 min) Frag=125.0V Ibu_10mgL_02.d "
#Point X(Thompsons) Y(Counts)
0 112.9867 2.91468031542248
1 117.0139 1.2276323922005
2 128.0302 1.23099864257052
3 145.0375 1.42226746225784
4 160.8291 1.20826452538619
```

and my chromatogram like this:

```
'#"- EIC(208.1300) Scan Ibu_10mgL_02.d "
#Point X(Minutes) Y(Counts)
0 0.05 0
1 0.07 0
2 0.09 0
3 0.10 0
4 0.12 0
```

I tried both `csvread` and `dlmread`. `dlmread`works without problem for the ms spectrum but not for the chromatogram. For me the files look the same.
When I try to import the chromatogram this is what i try:

`chrom = dlmread('ibu_test_chrom.txt','\t',2,1,[2 1 3595 1])`

and this is the error I got back from matlab:

```
Index exceeds the number of array elements (0).
Error in dlmread (line 152)
result = result{1};
```

I tried it also with: `chrom = dlmread('ibu_test_chrom.txt','\t',2,1)` but this does not work either.

Got someone a tip for me or a good example which can help me?

Comment: Did you try `readtable`? It often takes a lot of the pain out of reading well-formatted data tables since it does all of the data type work for you

Comment: I tried it, and it creates a table of 3598x1 instead of 3598x3. It seems to struggle with the variables: `chrom = readtable('ibu_test_chrom.txt')
Warning: Column headers from the file were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers
before creating variable names for the table. The original column headers are saved in the
VariableDescriptions property.
Set 'VariableNamingRule' to 'preserve' to use the original column headers as table variable
names.`

Comment: That's because your variable names contain brackets which cannot be MATLAB table variable names. If you want to avoid the warning then you could increase the header lines argument by 1 and set the `'ReadVariableNames'` option to false to ignore the var names, then set your own variable names with `tbl.Properties.VariableNames = {'A','B'}` or something similar. I suspect the odd variable names messed with the column splitting too, maybe specify the `'delimiter'` argument to use spaces.